# SSE2 integer overflow checking

Tags: c++, x86, sse, simd, sse2

When using SSE2 instructions such as `PADDD` (i.e., the `_mm_add_epi32` intrinsic), is there a way to check whether any of the operations overflowed?

I thought that maybe a flag on the MXCSR control register may get set after an overflow, but I don't see that happening. For example, `_mm_getcsr()` prints the same value in both cases below (8064):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <emmintrin.h>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    __m128i a = _mm_set_epi32(1, 0, 0, 0);
    __m128i b = _mm_add_epi32(a, a);
    cout << "MXCSR:  " << _mm_getcsr() << endl;
    cout << "Result: " << b.m128i_i32[3] << endl;

    __m128i c = _mm_set_epi32((1<<31)-1, 3, 2, 1);
    __m128i d = _mm_add_epi32(c, c);
    cout << "MXCSR:  " << _mm_getcsr() << endl;
    cout << "Result: " << d.m128i_i32[3] << endl;
}
```

Is there some other way to check for overflow with SSE2?

Comment: you could repeat the computation in saturation mode (PADDS) and compare the results.

Comment: Are you interested in signed or unsigned overflow?

Comment: @Dmitri: there is no 32 bit saturating add in SSE2 (only 8 bit and 16 bit)

Comment: It is possible that there are compiler intrisics for this. I know that Clang is in the process of adding them, and I would suppose gcc alreay has them, did you check ?

Comment: Alex: Ah, good point. I didn't realize that the two cases were different. Ideally, I would like to have a solution for both cases. I am working on an SSE-related library and so both cases are relevant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a somewhat more efficient version of [@hirschhornsalz's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/154980/hirschhornsalz) [`sum_and_overflow` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10513134/253056):

```
void sum_and_overflow(__v4si a, __v4si b, __v4si& sum, __v4si& overflow)
{
   __v4si sa, sb;

    sum = _mm_add_epi32(a, b);                  // calculate sum
    sa = _mm_xor_si128(sum, a);                 // compare sign of sum with sign of a
    sb = _mm_xor_si128(sum, b);                 // compare sign of sum with sign of b
    overflow = _mm_and_si128(sa, sb);           // get overflow in sign bit
    overflow = _mm_srai_epi32(overflow, 31);    // convert to SIMD boolean (-1 == TRUE, 0 == FALSE)
}
```

It uses an expression for overflow detection from [Hacker's Delight](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201914654) page 27:

```
sum = a + b;
overflow = (sum ^ a) & (sum ^ b);               // overflow flag in sign bit
```

Note that the overflow vector will contain the more conventional SIMD boolean values of -1 for TRUE (overflow) and 0 for FALSE (no overflow). If you only need the overflow in the sign bit and the other bits are "don't care" then you can omit the last line of the function, reducing the number of SIMD instructions from 5 to 4.

NB: this solution, as well as the [previous solution on which it is based](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10513134/253056) are for signed integer values. A solution for unsigned values will require a slightly different approach (see [@Stephen Canon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142434/stephen-canon)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571998/253056)).

Comment: Thanks! Those are some nice bit tricks, esp. the right shift to replicate the sign bit.

Comment: Worth highlighting this solution is valid for SIGNED values only - not UNSIGNED.

Comment: @SquareRootOfTwentyThree: thanks - that should be apparent from all the references to the sign bit etc, but I'll add a further sentence just to make it 100% clear.

Answer (score 9):

Since you have 4 possible overflows, the control register would very quickly run out of bits, especially, if you wanted carrys, sign etc. and that even for a vector addition consisting of 16 bytes :-)

The overflow flag is set, if the input sign bits are both equal and the result sign bit is different than a input sign bit.

This functions calculates `sum = a+b` and overflow manually. For every overflow 0x80000000 is returend in `overflow`.

```
void sum_and_overflow(__v4si a, __v4si b, __v4si& sum, __v4si& overflow) {
    __v4si signmask = _mm_set1_epi32(0x80000000);
    sum = a+b;
    a &= signmask;
    b &= signmask;
    overflow = sum & signmask;
    overflow = ~(a^b) & (overflow^a); // overflow is 1 if (a==b) and (resultbit has changed)
}
```

Note: If you don't have gcc, you have to replace the `^` `&` `+` operators by the appropriate SSE intrinsics, like `_mm_and_si128()`, `_mm_add_epi32()` etc.

Edit: I just noticed the `and` with the mask can of course be done at the very end of the function, saving two `and` operations. But the compiler will very likely be smart enough to do it by itself.

Comment: Thanks, drhirsch! I accepted Paul R's answer since that's one that makes most sense to highlight for posterity, but your answer was very helpful and I appreciate the time you took to write it up.

Answer (score 6):

I notice you asked for a solution for unsigned as well; fortunately, that's pretty easy too:

```
__v4si mask = _mm_set1_epi32(0x80000000);
sum = _mm_add_epi32(a, b);
overflow = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(_mm_xor_si128(mask, a), _mm_xor_si128(mask, sum));
```

Normally to detect unsigned overflow, you simply check either `sum < a` or `sum < b`.  However, SSE does not have unsigned comparisons; `xor`-ing the arguments with `0x80000000` lets you use a signed comparison to get the same result.

Comment: AVX512 finally adds unsigned comparisons: [`_mm512_cmp[eq|ge|gt|le|lt|neq]_epu32_mask`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/VPCMPD_VPCMPUD).  The full range of 8/16/32/64 bit element sizes are available for signed and unsigned (`epi` vs. `epu`), with an arbitrary comparison predicate instead of just `gt` and `eq` for AVX2 and earlier integer compares.

Comment: @PeterCordes *finally*!

Answer (score 2):

No flags are touched by the underlying [PADDD](http://www.rz.uni-karlsruhe.de/rz/docs/VTune/reference/vc223.htm) instruction.

So to test this, you have to write additional code, depending on what you want to do.

Note: You are a bit hindered by the lack of epi32 intrisics