# SSE4.1 unsigned integer comparison with overflow

Tags: assembly, x86, simd, sse2, sse4

Is there any way to perform a comparison like C >= (A + B) with SSE2/4.1 instructions considering 16 bit unsigned addition (`_mm_add_epi16()`) can overflow?

The code snippet looks like-

```
#define _mm_cmpge_epu16(a, b) _mm_cmpeq_epi16(_mm_max_epu16(a, b), a)

__m128i *a = (__m128i *)&ptr1;
__m128i *b = (__m128i *)&ptr2;
__m128i *c = (__m128i *)&ptr3;
            
_m128i xa = _mm_lddqu_si128(a);
_m128i xb = _mm_lddqu_si128(b);
_m128i xc = _mm_lddqu_si128(c);

_m128i res = _mm_add_epi16(xa, xb);
_m128i xmm3 = _mm_cmpge_epu16(xc, res);
```

The issue is that when the 16 bit addition overflows (wraps-around), the greater than comparison results in false positives. I can't use saturated addition for my purpose. I have looked at mechanism to detect overflow for unsigned addition here [SSE2 integer overflow checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511000/sse2-integer-overflow-checking/10571998#10571998). But how how do I use if for greater than comparision.

Comment: I think you should first check for overflow as per the question you linked. If you do detect an overflow, you know that `C > (A + B)` is false. Otherwise, check that next. Since you are doing vectors, you might have to perform both checks and merge them using bitwise operations. (Edited to fix reversed condition).

Comment: Do you want to check `C > (A+B)` or `C >= (A+B)`? In the first case, I don't see how adding with saturation leads to false positives.

Comment: Edited - its C >= (A + B)

Comment: I think `C-A >= B` (with saturated subtraction) should work (not tested). Edit: No it does not (need to think more about it)

Comment: @chtz: if we know `C` can't be `0xffff`, does it help to do saturating `A+B` then range-shift both C and the sum to signed (by flipping their sign bits with `pxor`) for `pcmpgtw`?  But if it has to work for C = 0xffff, same as the saturation result, I don't think that helps.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, and the `C-A >= B` trick would work if one of  `B>0` or `C>=A` is guaranteed. (Similar for `C-B >= A`, of course). One could check `C-min(A,B) >= max(A,B)` which would be 5 uops, if I count correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You build the missing primitives from what you have available in the instruction set.
Here’s one possible implementation, untested. [Disassembly](https://godbolt.org/z/E38G5r).

```
// Compare uint16_t lanes for a >= b
inline __m128i cmpge_epu16( __m128i a, __m128i b )
{
    const __m128i max = _mm_max_epu16( a, b );
    return _mm_cmpeq_epi16( max, a );
}

// Compare uint16_t lanes for c >= a + b, with overflow handling
__m128i cmpgeSum( __m128i a, __m128i b, __m128i c )
{
    // Compute c >= a + b, ignoring overflow issues
    const __m128i sum = _mm_add_epi16( a, b );
    const __m128i ge = cmpge_epu16( c, sum );

    // Detect overflow of a + b
    const __m128i sumSaturated = _mm_adds_epu16( a, b );
    const __m128i sumInRange = _mm_cmpeq_epi16( sum, sumSaturated );

    // Combine the two
    return _mm_and_si128( ge, sumInRange );
}
```

Comment: Just a corner case to be handled when c is 0xFFFF and  a+b overflows.

Comment: @Kaustubh What do you mean? https://godbolt.org/z/z6hGzE

Comment: Thanks. It was an issue with my test. It's acceptance answer for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few reasonable approaches:

```
#include <cstdint>
using v8u16 = uint16_t __attribute__((vector_size(16)));

v8u16 lthsum1(v8u16 a, v8u16 b, v8u16 c) {
    return (c >= a) & (c - a >= b);
}

v8u16 lthsum2(v8u16 a, v8u16 b, v8u16 c) {
    return (a + b >= a) & (a + b <= c);
}
```

You can see how this gets compiled on
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KTM3f6). Both approaches are broadly equivalent, and I'm not seeing large changes with `-msse4.1` with gcc, but AVX2 and later do improve the code. [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/4vP6qh) also gets minor improvements with sse4.1 for the second variant. With [AVX512BW](https://godbolt.org/z/sG9jrx), clang does pretty well for itself.